# how to resolve Object Invalid Value: because the given value '' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am getting this error when I run *developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.joyatwork.co*.
The page code contains:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

Is the "" misinterpreted as " or what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`og:image` is empty, either remove it or supply the url for the image. Also use double quotes for your meta properties

e.g.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Príbeh o novom začiatku" />
```